# Java GAE Endpoints - Model class methods missing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a GAE application which uses JDO (lets say "Score"), and I've created some endpoints which use these JDO objects. When I generate the Cloud Endpoint Client the frameworks puts the class "Score" in the client library, but it's very streamlined.

All setter/getter, which are public in the GAE app are missing (for example). Is there a way to have setter/getters in the client version of the class?

I'm using Android

Answer (score 0):

That sounds wrong.

You haven't mentioned what your client platform, but I imagine they are all similar.  For me, on Android, the generated classes have getters/setters.

You should be looking in "com.google.api.services.yourendpoint.model.Score.java".  If it doesn't have getters/setters then something has gone wrong.  Perhaps you should check the error log to see if there was an error during client library generation.

Did the endpoint code get generated properly?  Do you see the client implementation of your endopints in com.google.api.services.yourendpoint.Yourendpoint.java?